# Generation of a database containing combinations of different abundances of different variables.

Tags: analysis

I’m working on a problem where I have 20 minerals (a to t) that may be present in a rock in different proportions - what those proportions are defines the rock type. Each rock type has certain rules about the proportions of minerals it can contain.

For example, Rock A must have ≥ 85% mineral a, ≤ 15% combined of minerals b, c and d, ≤ 15% combined of minerals e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q and r, ≤ 15% mineral s and ≤ 15% mineral t.

I was hoping to be able to create a database for each rock type that contains every possible combination of mineral proportions for that rock type using 1% increments for each mineral proportion.

> e.g., for Rock A:
>
> > a=100%, b=0%, c=0%, d=0%... t=0%
> >
> > > a=99%, b=1%, c=0%, d=0%... t=0%
> > >
> > > > a=99%, b=0%, c=1%, d=0%... t=0%
> > > >         etc.

If the number of combinations is simply too large other rules could be added like "of the minerals e to r, only a maximum of 5 may be present together in any rock."

Can anyone help me out or point me in a helpful direction? Thanks :)

Comment: What about a=99.5%? The percentages are probably not discrete so you would need an infinite number of entries in your database.

Comment: Using 1% increments

Comment: Seeing as you simply want us to point *you* in the right direction then we are going to need a little more information about *you*. First of all, how do you typically store your data? From what I can understand, you want a simple method of writing down all of the combinations. Is this correct?

Comment: That's correct Diatche. So far i've just been using excel but am open to anything else that may be more suitable.